Intermittent Selenium WebDriver Exception "disconnected: unable to send message to renderer: not connected to DevTools" (ChromeDriver V124)
I have Selenium tests in Visual Studio on the .Net framework using ChromeDriver. The tests were running fine until the latest ChromeDriver update 124.
I've been getting intermittent errors while running the tests through Visual Studio 2022 as shown below. Essentially the Chrome browser closes during the test which leads to the error being thrown. The browser closes at random places during the test.The Chrome Browser and Chrome Driver are up to date and are compatible with each other. I have the latest version of Selenium (4.20.0), Visual Studio 2022 is up to date, Windows has all the latest updates installed.
Error Message:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.156)

I am using the following ChromeOptions:
optn.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
optn.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
optn.AddArgument("--no-first-run");
optn.AddArgument("--disable-fre");
optn.AddArgument("--no-default-browser-check");
optn.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
optn.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
optn.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
optn.AddArgument("--test-type");
optn.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
optn.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
optn.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
optn.AddArguments("start-maximized");
optn.AddExcludedArgument("--enable-automation");

Note: The tests cannot be ran in Headless mode.
My PC is not in sleep mode when the error occurs.
Things I have tried:
I rebooted my system.
I ran the tests in Visual Studio 2019 and still got the same error.
I uninstalled recently installed windows security updates, no difference, so I reinstalled them.
I have tried other ChromeDriver versions, but these fail due to incompatibility with the installed version of Chrome. I cannot revert the installed Chrome to an earlier version.
Nothing has changed since the tests were running fine except ChromeDriver updated to 124.
Thanks for reading this, is there anything else I could try?

if you need to revert to an older version of the driver you can set an environment variable to disable the version check.  In java you'd do: System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");  Not sure of .net equivalent.

I Have Exactly Same Problem

@browsermator Thanks for your input, I tried reverting to an older web driver, but it wasn't compatible with the version of the browser. I cannot revert the version of the browser on the test machine. I'm now using Version 125 of the Chrome Driver and Broswer, and I am still getting the issue

@zobydehkarimi Sorry to heat that! I still haven't resolved this. If you have any luck please let me know

I update to latest chrome driver . Decrease error . Check with latest chrome driver .
